# how to insert timestamp beyond the limitation of keep in tdengine

Tags: tdengine

I found that tdengine has a parameter will create database. this definition "The KEEP parameter refers to the number of days to save a modified data file. " from tdengine's website https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/taos-sql#management.  I think this parameter is very useful that there is no need to delete the history data. so i create a database which only keep 10 days.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_keep KEEP 10 PRECISION 'ms' ;
create table test_keep(ts timestamp,desc nchar(20));
```

after create db and table , I tried to insert some data into the table. the follows are my insert sqls.

```
insert into test_keep values(now,'now');
insert into test_keep values('2021-08-31 10:28:53.521','yesterday');
insert into test_keep values('2021-09-02 10:28:53.521','tomorrow');
insert into test_keep values('2021-08-25 10:28:53.521','6 days before');
insert into test_keep values('2021-09-20 12:28:53.521','20 days later');
insert into test_keep values('2021-08-21 10:28:53.521','10 days before');
insert into test_keep values('2021-08-11 10:28:53.521','20 days before');
```

While the lass three sql had execute error "DB error: Timestamp data out of range"

> taos> insert into test_keep values(now,'now'); Query OK, 1 of 1 row(s)
> in database (1.024000s)
>
> taos> insert into test_keep values('2021-08-31
> 10:28:53.521','yesterday'); Query OK, 1 of 1 row(s) in database
> (0.006000s)
>
> taos> insert into test_keep values('2021-09-02
> 10:28:53.521','tomorrow'); Query OK, 1 of 1 row(s) in database
> (0.004000s)
>
> taos> insert into test_keep values('2021-08-25 10:28:53.521','6 days
> before'); Query OK, 1 of 1 row(s) in database (0.004000s)
>
> taos> insert into test_keep values('2021-09-20 12:28:53.521','20 days
> later');
>
> DB error: Timestamp data out of range (0.005000s) taos> insert into
> test_keep values('2021-08-21 10:28:53.521','10 days before');
>
> DB error: Timestamp data out of range (0.004000s) taos> insert into
> test_keep values('2021-08-11 10:28:53.521','20 days before');
>
> DB error: Timestamp data out of range (0.004000s) taos>

I thought this because of my keep is to small, so i made it larger.

```
ALTER DATABASE db_keep KEEP 365;
```

and the I tried to insert the failed sql again I  found cannot insert data some days later from now .

> taos> insert into test_keep values('2021-09-20 12:28:53.521','20 days
> later');
>
> DB error: Timestamp data out of range (0.005000s) taos> insert into
> test_keep values('2021-08-21 10:28:53.521','10 days before'); Query
> OK, 1 of 1 row(s) in database (0.004000s)
>
> taos> insert into test_keep values('2021-08-11 10:28:53.521','20 days
> before'); Query OK, 1 of 1 row(s) in database (0.004000s)

I want to ask how to use keep and the how dose it limit the data's timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

For past data, the timestamp value cannot exceed `(current_time - keep)`. Meanwhile, for future data, the timestamp value cannot exceed `(current time + days)`.

Since my reputation is not enough for inserting images here, please refer to reference link below for details (**grey means can NOT be inserted**).

Reference:

1. https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000040617572

Answer (score 0):

For timestamp in a database, the two configuration options is most reasonable:

1. `keep`: the longest days to keep in the database refer to current timestamp(3650 days by default). When the "newest" timestamp in a persist file goes out of the range, the persist file will be deleted. Timestamp older than `now - keep` will be treated as `Timestamp out of range`.
2. `days`: the time range to store data in a file, 10 days by default. Newer timestamp would not be larger than `now+ days`.

So, the acceptale timestamp range in a database will be `[now - keep, now + days]`.